# How many problem statements should I create?

Tags: user-research, ux-field, user-centered-design, design-thinking

I'm learning UX design, I've decided to start my first project and right now and in the **define** stage. But I've got a doubt. How many problem statements should I create?
In the empathize stage I've identified 2 group of users, so I developed 2 personas, should I create a problem statement for each persona?

Comment: there's no limit to how many problem statements you need to have per persona. but maybe you should 1st identify the problems and then analyse if these problems are pointing to a major problem or root cause. solving this could potentially address the rest of the issues.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific number of prob statements,you could Write 10 prob statement for each persona but which prob do you tackle first then? That is the key. Which one are they actually trying to solve? If they are actively trying to solve 3,tackle the Most doable. So Write as many as you want for practice but then choose.